# Kony Forms - produced in what form?

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am trying to understand the form in which the mobile UI portion of a KonyOne Studio hybrid app is produced and whether I can have a disconnected hybrid app.  As I understand it now for hybrid apps (Web and native parts), Forms in the KonyOne Designer get converted into JSPs.  Is that correct?  Can I assume this type of app must run connected all the time so that the JSP output is always up to date?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a little misunderstanding here:

- When the output is Hybrid, the forms are converted to a SPA ( Single Page Application, a feature of HTML5 ), and embedded with the application itself.
- The Hybrid shell is a native application, and there are javascript bindings between the content on the form ( which is in HTML5 ) and the shell ( which is pure native )
- The SPA portion of the application only needs to be connected to the network when Service calls are being made.  So to answer your question, you can have an "offline" ( non-network connected ) application, as long as you are not going back to the server for data.  For data calls, you will need to be connected.